# Scala mixin traits error

Tags: scala

The following code snippet:

```
scala> trait User { def name: String }
defined trait User

scala> trait Tweeter {
     | user: User =>
     | def tweet(msg: String) = println(s"$name: $msg")
     | }
defined trait Tweeter

scala> trait Correct extends Tweeter with User { }
defined trait Correct

scala> trait Wrong extends Tweeter
<console>:9: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Wrong does not conform to Tweeter's selftype Tweeter with User
       trait Wrong extends Tweeter
                           ^

scala>
```

Tweeter has-a User, then why would one need to mix User in when extending Tweeter? Wrong is still a trait! Why would I need to mix User?

Comment: Could it be that anybody who extends Wrong might forget or not inject User if it is not explicitly mixed in Wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tweeter` does not have a `User`, it requires that whatever mixes in `Tweeter` is one (is or mixes in `User`).

`trait Wrong` does not mix in `User`, so it fails to conform to the self-type of `Tweeter`.

You either need to mix `User` into `Wrong` like you're doing with `Correct`, *or* `Wrong` must also require `User` as a self-type to conform to `Tweeter`'s self-type.

```
trait Wrong extends Tweeter { self: User => }
```

Comment: Is self a keyword or just an alias?

Comment: @user3102968 Just an alias. I could have called it `user` here.